# LastBatch in result of sp_who2 is set to 01/01

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-connection, sp-who2

I executed stored procedure `sp_who2 'Active'`.
In result I got list of active connections to db. But I also noticed that there are  some connections where LastBatch equals to 01/01.

What does it mean? There are some queries that is never executed, but connection to db is still available?

[image]

Comment: According to [this](https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/lastbatch-mastersysprocesses), that will be displayed for connections created without using RPC calls. Unfortunately the link it refers to 404s, and I'm having trouble finding anything more recent to confirm it.

Comment: @Diado thx, your article helps!